# Анимация png картинки

Tags: html, css, css-animation

[image: Скролл страницы]

Есть вот такая картинка. Надо чтобы она беспрерывно меняла цвет на желтый сверху вниз. Возможно ли это сделать и если да, то как?

Comment: Во-первых, пнг не может менять цвет сама по себе (без дублирования или ещё каких-то хитростей), во-вторых, что значит "беспрерывно"? У желтого цвета есть потолок желтезны. Я бы сказал, что тут без svg не обойдется

Comment: @Khipster, если двигать, то она будет двигаться ... ты наверное имел ввиду наложить поверх и менять высоту. Но тогда не будет плавного перехода ... тут конечно зависит от конкретной задачи, тут мне кажется имеется ввиду все же плавный переход цвета

Comment: @MedvedevDev попробую описать подробно....на странице размещается эта картинка, нужно сделать анимацию с помощью которой, картинка постепенно плавно сверху вниз будет заливаться желтым цветом. И нужно сделать так чтобы эта анимация повторялась

Comment: @MedvedevDev Должна быть просто анимация

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, картинка становится желтой, потом сверху вниз ставноится опять серой и по кругу

Comment: Сделать анимацию в графическом редакторе в формате gif не проще?

Comment: @IgorGolovin хотелось бы сделать на css

Comment: CSS не умеет изменять PNG, вам нужен <canvas>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действительно задачка веселая ... да простят меня все кто увидит этот мой "шедевр", я честно старался ...

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 66px;
  height: 77px;
  height: 
  font-size: 0;
}

.icon_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: colorizeOut 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.icon_container__yellow {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  animation: colorizeIn 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.icon_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon_container__yellow .icon_image {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}

@keyframes colorizeIn {
 0% { min-height: 0; }
 100% { min-height: 77px; }
}

@keyframes colorizeOut {
 0% { min-height: 77px; }
 100% { min-height: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <div class="icon_container">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/Ou00Phd.png" class="icon_image">
  </div>
  <div class="icon_container icon_container__yellow">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/yCnqsy6.png" class="icon_image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уже близко к истине. Вот только можете исправить чтобы после заливки желтым цветом, картинка сразу возвращалась в исходное состояние и затем снова окрашивалась в желтый

Comment: Ну ё маё, а я так долго именно с данным эффектом боролся .... ну нет так нет, хозяин - барин, сейчас поубираю лишнее

Comment: @Nikita Knyazev Убрал лишнее, теперь видимо то что нужно, но прежний вариант мне нравился больше, зря пытался его добиться (

Comment: Поставил анимацию на 2.5 секунды и стало прям идеально. Спасибо большое и извините что помучил))

Comment: @Nikita Knyazev на самом деле одна из самых нетривиальных задач за последние дни (хоть и кажется таково), было интересно, а самое крутое, что ещё пару интересных решений накидали )))

Comment: Согласен по поводу решений)

Answer (score 1):

Фух, знаешь, это было сложно. Я как-то искал уже такое, но не находил. А щас на 20 минут больше погуглил - и нашел.

Вся загвоздка в mask, [у него плохая поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.wrapper-for-image {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 66px;
  height: 77px;
}

div.back {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lSyw.png) no-repeat;
}

div.front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lSyw.png) no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, #504f4f) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px -77px;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background-position 1s ease 0s, background-size 1s ease 0s;
}

div.front:hover {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-for-image">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Можно было бы использовать если не плохая поддержка браузерами. И еще один момент, работает только при наведении.

Comment: @NikitaKnyazev, ну да, если бы не поддержка... А при чем тут наведение? Делай как угодно, я сделал ховер чисто чтобы показать, как оно работает. Можно и статическую анимацию повесить.

Comment: Все равно спасибо, полезно было узнать о таком свойстве

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто сделать несколько версий цветовых этой картинки, и через Jquery сделать чтобы они менялись

Comment: Нужно без использования скрипта

Comment: На SVG напиши. Так будет проще и без скрипта.

Comment: А как сделать это с помощью svg? Можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

Пример с использованием [hue-rotate](https://webref.ru/css/value/hue-rotate)

[Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=hue-rotate)

```css
.b{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.b:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: url(http://static.wixstatic.com/media/4b5ed0_f915a7d25461495bb9008e09fe48a446.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  animation: animPicture 3s linear infinite;
 }
 
@keyframes animPicture{
  0{
    height: 0;
  } 
  99%{    
     -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0);
  filter: hue-rotate(0);
  }
  100%{
    height: 100%;   
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/4b5ed0_f915a7d25461495bb9008e09fe48a446.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Также как вариант сделать 2 картинки и анимировать их.

Comment: А как сделать желтый цвет? Не нашел, где вы задали значение цвета

Comment: https://webcode.tools/css-generator/hue-rotate